# Mouse unresponsive after login

Tags: touchpad, mouse

Out of nowhere the mouse on my Asus S430 has become unresponsive.

The mouse works just fine under Windows or during the Elementary login screen, but does not respond to movement or clicks after login.

xinput shows the touchpad to be enabled.

Any idea what the problem might be?